# Teechart on Monotouch: where is the documentation?

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

Downloaded eval for Teechart for Monotouch iOS. Looks very promising. Could not find documentation though except windows help chm. Are there any docs available on the web?

Also running an example on iPad discovered that pan and zoom are extremely slow unless set to Auto.

chart3.Chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Auto;

Why?

Comment: This would probably be a good question to ask the vendor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Downloaded eval for Teechart for Monotouch iOS. Looks very promising. Could not find documentation though except windows help chm. Are there any docs available on the web?

Yes, you can download on our web site throught this [link](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/net/TeeChartNET4_CHM_Library_Help.zip).

> Also running an example on iPad discovered that pan and zoom are extremely slow unless set to Auto.
>   Why?

This was the reason we introduced the ZoomScrollStyles property, setting it to Auto, the chart will use the standard zoom and scroll gestures used for iOS (for most common 2D chart styles), meanwhile setting it to Manual, the chart will make use of the default zoom and scroll functionality based on the TeeChart for NET product.